# Why does my iPod Touch automatically turn the volume all the way down?

Tags: ipod-touch, audio

I have an 8GB iPod Touch, 4th generation.  Recently it has been automatically turning the volume all the way down, and it often won't let me turn it back up again.  This happens both when I'm using headphones and when I'm not.  It has also been restarting itself automatically.  It hasn't always done this--I've had it since December 2010, and it started doing it in May 2011.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you notice this when switching between headphones in and out? There are at least three distinct volume settings on the device: no headphones (internal speaker), regular headphones, and headphones with remote and mic. Are you noticing settings changes that this is affecting?

Answer (score 3):

Three things can cause this:

1. The down button is now physically pressed (or the electrical contact has shorted/failed)
2. The headphone jack is sensing a volume button press (much less likely)
3. software is corrupt (very very unlikely, but still possible)
4. bluetooth remote (also very very unlikely)

You can restore the device to rule out #3. Turning off bluetooth nixes #4. You might be able to rule out #2 by trying some different headphones, but I've seen that fail in ways that headphones in or out won't help. You'll need a repair / exchange to fix the first two issues if it's not caused by a temporary piece of debris or light cleaning with clean, dry lightly compressed air.

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same problem with my iPod. I've found a temporary but helpful fix is to physically depress the down volume button with quite a bit of pressure a few times. If the volume button is stuck, depressing it a few times seems to jolt it loose.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by just doing a reset on all settings, no need to erase data.  Was sticking on no volume

Answer (score 0):

Try a squirt of WD-40 in the volume down button. Worked for me.

Comment: Might be dangerous to put oil into your phone though...